# Why GET (JAX-RS) doesn't return inherited entity specific information?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, get, jax-rs

I am running a RESTful web service on Glassfish 3.1.2 server. I use Jersey as JAX-RS implementation, Jackson as it's JSON provider, and (JPA) EclipseLink 2.5 as persistence provider for MySQL.

I'll introduce some context and then ask my question.
Let's assume we have the following hierarchy: `Item` entity and `CraftableItem` entity that inherits it (see code samples below). They both do have corresponding EAO and Resource classes: `ItemEAO`, `CraftableItemEAO` + `ItemResource`, `CraftableItemResource` (see code samples  below).

Let's have two records in `items` table:

```
id | name 
 1 | "craftable"
 2 | "non craftable"
```

and one corresponding record for "craftable" in `crafting_items_joined`:

```
id | crafting_time
 1 | 120000
```

**I want to get as more specific information about each entity from `GET /item` request as possible.** I want it to return `[{"id":1,"name":"craftable", "crafting_time":120000}, {"id":2,"name":"non craftable"}]`. At the momment, `GET /item/1` returns `{"id":1,"name":"craftable", "crafting_time":120000}` and `GET /item/2` returns just `{"id":2,"name":"non craftable"}` **which is the behavior i want, but for `GET /item`. Getting all information about entity present.**

Code samples (setters are omitted for sanity's sake).

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    protected Long id;
    
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "items")
public class Item extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("craftable")
@Table(name = "craftable_items_joined")
public class CraftableItem extends Item {
    
    protected long craftingTime;

    @Column(name = "crafting_time", nullable = false)
    public long getCraftingTime() {
        return craftingTime;
    }
}
```

EAO then:

```
public abstract class AbstractEAO<T> {

    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractEAO(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    public Class<T> getEntityClass() {
        return entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    // create, edit, remove

    public T find(Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }
}

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ItemEAO extends AbstractEAO<Item> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "primary")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public ItemEAO() {
        super(Item.class);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    } 
}

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class CraftableItemEAO extends AbstractEAO<CraftableItem> {
    
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "primary")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public CraftableItemEAO() {
        super(CraftableItem.class);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }    
}
```

Resource finally:

```
public abstract class AbstractResource<T extends BaseEntity> {
    
    protected abstract AbstractEAO<T> getEAO();
    
    @GET
    public List<T> findAll() {
        return getEAO().findAll();
    }
    
    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    public T find(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        return getEAO().find(id);
    }

    // create, edit, remove
}

@Stateless
@Path("item")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ItemResource extends AbstractResource<Item> {

    @EJB private ItemEAO itemEAO;
    
    @Override
    protected AbstractEAO<Item> getEAO() {
        return itemEAO;
    }
}

@Stateless
@Path("item/craftable")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class CraftableItemResource extends AbstractResource<CraftableItem> {
    
    @EJB private CraftableItemEAO craftableItemEAO;

    @Override
    protected AbstractEAO<CraftableItem> getEAO() {
        return craftableItemEAO;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, and what the problem is. I read your question as "I want it to return foo, and it returns foo, which is what I want". So, what's the problem?

Comment: Well not quite. I get specific information (specified in subclass) only on single resource request (`GET /item/{id}`), which is what I want. But on multiple resource request (`GET /item`) that **doesn't** happen - I get just common information (specified in superclass) for each entity.

Comment: Hi. Did you solve the problem? I'm having a similar problem.